# ANR при String.split

Tags: android, строки, split

Использую для своих текстов классы для выравнивания текста с ГитХаба. [Вот эти](https://github.com/nikoo28/justify-textview-android)

Последнее время один из пользователей стал получать вот такой ANR (по логам из маркета):

```
#00  pc 000000000001f2ec  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #00  pc 00000000000e0494  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #00  pc 00000000003805e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::GetIntArrayElements(_JNIEnv*, _jintArray*, unsigned char*)+484)
  #00  pc 0000000000023268  /system/lib64/libjavacore.so (MatcherState::updateOffsets(_JNIEnv*, _jintArray*)+60)
  #00  pc 0000000000023004  /system/lib64/libjavacore.so (Matcher_findNextImpl(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, _jintArray*)+64)
  at java.util.regex.Matcher.findNextImpl (Native method)
  at java.util.regex.Matcher.find (Matcher.java:482)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern.split (Pattern.java:1127)
  at java.lang.String.split (String.java:2455)
  at java.lang.String.split (String.java:2497)
  at com.(мой_домен).(мой_пакет).TextJustifyUtils.createWrappedLine (TextJustifyUtils.java:100)
  at com.(мой_домен).(мой_пакет).TextViewEx.onDraw (TextViewEx.java:162)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20483)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19294)
  ...и т.д. в том же духе
```

Фрагмент кода с ошибкой:

```
 protected static Object[] createWrappedLine(String block, Paint paint, float spaceOffset, float maxWidth) {
        float cacheWidth = maxWidth;
        float origMaxWidth = maxWidth;
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

      !!!  for (String word : block.split("\\s")) { <== ANR вылетает здесь

            cacheWidth = paint.measureText(word);
            maxWidth -= cacheWidth;
            if (maxWidth <= 0) {
                return new Object[]{line.toString(), maxWidth + cacheWidth + spaceOffset};
            }
            line.append(word).append(" ");
            maxWidth -= spaceOffset;
        }
        if (paint.measureText(block) <= origMaxWidth) {
            return new Object[]{block, Float.MIN_VALUE};
        }
        return new Object[]{line.toString(), maxWidth};
    }
```

Текстов в приложении много, но вылетает только один. И далеко не у всех.
Вынести в отдельный поток не получается - работаю с отображением текста.

Не понимаю, как оставить Split и побороть ANR.

Comment: `Вынести в отдельный поток не получается - работаю с отображением текста` - почему именно не получается? Какую-то ошибку кидает?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб из функции надо возвращать значение, чтобы оно обсчитывалось в момент отрисовки, иначе будет возвращать и обсчитывать пустой Object[], а потом "догонять"... отложенная отрисовка (если даже ее реализовать) может вызвать другие проблемы/костыли (текст в диалоге и возникает не надолго) - я так это вижу.

Comment: `обсчитывалось в момент отрисовки` - т.е. оно уже после отображения текста должно высчитываться чтобы отображение как-то обновить? Т.е. вариант сначала посчитать а потом отображать диалог не подходит?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это сторонний класс с Гита, не сильно хочется лезть. Но в принципе да, как вариант (если других нет), надо попробовать побольше подумать в эту сторону. Да вообще интересно, чо вдруг АНР стал на сплите выскакивать... Причём на единичном устройстве

Comment: Я бы сильно не удивлялся - всё ж там регулярка, хоть и не сложная. На мой взгляд от регулярок стоит ожидать проблем, в т.ч. с производительностью)

Comment: Поддержу @ЮрийСПб. Я бы переписал `split("\\s")` на что-то ручное без регулярки,  тем более что код там не весь бог какой.

Comment: без регулярки тоже не получается. Заменил ее циклическим перебором строки через indexOf(" "), всё равно ANR... Видимо придётся делать предварительный обсчёт.